# Is it OK to say "the staff of this hotel"?

Tags: sentence-construction

What I want to say is that I have been in touched with someone who work in a specific hotel, so, is it OK to say to my boss this?

> I have contacted with the staff of the hotel.

Comment: You can say: *I have been in touch with the staff/manager...* or *I have contacted the staff/manager/hotel....*  You cannot say *I have contacted WITH the staff...* but you can say: *I have made contact with the staff....*

Answer (score 2):

You could say

> I have contacted the staff of the hotel.

or

> I have been **in** contact with the staff of the hotel.

of

> I have had contact *with* the staff of the hotel.

All have the same meaning as you intend.

Comment: Slight nuance though - the first one suggests a one-way conversation, the second and third clearly indicate a two-way conversation.